# tf id frame odom_combined and base_footprint does not exist error

Tags: ros, odom-combined, base-footprint, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, how are you doing guys? Hope you are doing great.

I'm writing this message because I'm having problems with the pr2_controller tutorial: "Using the base controller with odometry and transform information", even though that the first time I ran it it worked fine. Let me explain everything I've done to see if anybody can find what is wrong.

The first time I ran it it gave me this error:

```
drive_base_tutorial$ bin/odometry_base terminate called after throwing an instance of 'tf::LookupException' what(): Frame id /base_footprint does not exist! When trying to transform between /odom_combined and /base_footprint. Aborted
```

After looking a little on the internet (I after realized that this was explained on the tutorial too) I found a girl with the exact same problem and somebody told her to use:

```
bin/odometry_base cmd_vel:=base_controller/command
```

I did it and it worked. I tried to use the same instruction on the same terminal to move the robot again, but the terminal froze. I dismissed this incident believing that I couldn't use the same instruction on the same terminal two times. I closed the terminal, ended the simulation, turned off the computer and went to lunch. I came back and tried to run it again and now everything is screwed.
I try to run the simulation again and I keep getting:

```
drive_base_tutorial$  bin/odometry_base cmd_vel:=base_controller/command terminate called after throwing an instance of 'tf::LookupException'  what():  Frame id /base_footprint does not exist! When trying to transform between /odom_combined and /base_footprint. Aborted
```

or even

```
drive_base_tutorial$  bin/odometry_base cmd_vel:=base_controller/command terminate called after throwing an instance of 'tf::LookupException' what():  Frame id /odom_combined does not exist! When trying to transform between /odom_combined and /base_footprint. Aborted
```

I've checked

```
rosrun tf tf_monitor base_footprint odom_combined
```

and it just keeps drawing points without telling me nothing. I've also tried:

```
rosrun tf tf_echo base_footprint odom_combined
```

and again it tells me that one of the frames do not exist.
I erased the package drive_base_tutorial and did everything from the beginning and nothing.
My questions are:
What is this frame odom_combined? I know that base_footprint is created on the pr2 URDF, but I can't find this odom_combined anywhere. Is it in any controller of the pr2? which one?.

Can't I change it for other existing frame? on the turtlesim/tf tutorials they use a "world" frame. Is there a world frame for gazebo? if there is, how is it called? I've tried changing odom_combined for world but this frame doesn't exist either.

I've found tutorials that teaches you how to add a new frame, but is a new child frame, can I create a world frame from scratch? how?

Please help me. Also consider that I'm very new to programming so please have patience. Sorry it was such a long history, but I do really want to understand what is going on.

Thanks for you time, patience and for any help you can give me.

By the way, I'm using Diamondback version of ROS with Ubuntu Maverick.
Remember also that the program worked the first time. So I don't know what happened.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10460/tf-id-frame-odom_combined-and-base_footprint-does-not-exist-error/) by [Aidan1488](https://answers.ros.org/users/777/aidan1488/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2011-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No activity > 1 month, closing

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

/odom_combined comes from the robot_pose_ekf, is that running?

If you do "rosrun tf view_frames" does it show that the tf graph is in fact a proper tree? Are transforms coming at a regular rate? (information about rates will be in the frames.pdf created by view_frames)

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-07-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aidan1488](https://answers.ros.org/users/777/aidan1488/) on 2011-07-07**:
Yes robot_pose_ekf is running. If I use the command bin/odometry_base many times it eventually works. The failure must be the rate differences between frames then. Still I'll like to know how to create a world frame in gazebo since I'm creating my own robot URDF. Is odom_combined a world frame?

**Comment by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) on 2011-07-06**:
When you run 'rosnode list', do you see the robot_pose_ekf somewhere? The robot_pose_ekf is publishing the odom_combined frame to tf.

**Comment by [Aidan1488](https://answers.ros.org/users/777/aidan1488/) on 2011-07-06**:
If I run view_frames I can see the base_link frame (which is parent of base_footprint) but no mention of odom_combined :s that I forgot to mention, is the main reason of my question... I can't find the dumb thing anywhere...:(